# C# - can I retrieve the seed value n iterations off of the original seed?

Tags: c#, random

I don't know if this functionality is possible, but it would be very helpful for my current project.

I want to be able to generate a list of characters that will be able to be regenerated at a later time. So I seed the character list to 0, and get 80 characters that are designed.

Now, at a later point, I need to be able to generate this list of characters, but I don't need the first 20 characters. I don't want to seed it to same value, and then have to throw out much of the work. Is there a way I can determine what the seed value would be, or is it even possible to have it function this way, where I start part-way through the generation, and then continue on as if I was on the old seed.

For example, I generate the following list:

`56, 12, 0, 84, 24, ...n,...95, 25, 72, 57, 15`

Now, I need to generate the last 5 values from the list only. ie: 95, 25, 72, 57, 15.

Is there a way to "jump" to this point in the random generation algorithm without having to re-run all of the random calls like this? To be clear, I don't want to do the following:

```
Random.seed = 123;
for(int i = 0; i < skippableRandomValues; ++i)
{
    Random.Range(0,1);
}
GenerateRandomCharacter();
```

If I could cache the required seed to start generating from a specific point in the list for instance, then I could load up the cached seed, and start the generation process without having to burn through my CPU. Something like this:

```
Random.seed = 123;
for(int i = 0; i < CharactersToGenerate; ++i)
{
    int seedVal = Random.GetContinuousSeedVal();
    CharacterSeedStartValues[i]=seedVal
    GenerateRandomCharacter();
}
```

So the first value of `CharacterSeedStartValues` would be 123,then, after generation, I could store the value needed to generate character 1, then 2, ..., n.

Then, when I only want to generate character 54, I can simply call:

```
Random.seed = CharacterSeedStartValues[53];
GenerateRandomCharacter();
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: What you are searching for is a RNG (random number generator) that supports a feature called "jump ahead" or "leapfrogging". I'm very sure that the RNG in C# does not support this kind of operation but maybe there is some kind of third party implementation.

Comment: IMHO just use a hash function instead. `Hash('some root value' + 'index')`. Then use that as a seed for each character.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own implementation of a decent RNG such as [XorShift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift). Then you could add your own method to return the current RNG state so you could restore it in order to skip any number of iterations.

For example, here's a C# implementation of a version of [XorShift from here](https://xorshift.di.unimi.it/xorshift1024star.c):

```
public sealed class XorShift : System.Random
{
    public XorShift(ulong seed1, ulong seed2)
    {
        if (seed1 == 0 && seed2 == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("seed1 and seed 2 cannot both be zero.");

        _s[0] = seed1;
        _s[1] = seed2;

        init();
    }

    public XorShift() : this(Guid.NewGuid())
    {
    }

    public XorShift(Guid seed)
    {
        var bytes = seed.ToByteArray();

        _s[0] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0);
        _s[1] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 8);

        init();
    }

    public XorShift(int p, ulong[] s)
    {
        if (s.Length != 16)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("s", "s must be exactly 16 long.");

        _p = p;
        _s = s.ToArray();
    }

    public (int P, ulong[] S) State()
    {
        return (_p, _s.ToArray());
    }

    public ulong NextUlong()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            ulong s0 = _s[_p];
            _p = (_p + 1) & 15;
            ulong s1 = _s[_p];
            s1 ^= s1 << 31;
            _s[_p] = s1 ^ s0 ^ (s1 >> 11) ^ (s0 >> 30);
            return _s[_p] * 0x9e3779b97f4a7c13UL;
        }
    }

    public long NextLong(long maxValue)
    {
        return NextLong(0, maxValue);
    }

    public long NextLong(long minValue, long maxValue)
    {
        if (minValue == maxValue || minValue == maxValue - 1)
            return minValue;

        double range = (double)maxValue - minValue;
        var result = (long)(NextDouble() * range) + minValue;

        return result;
    }

    public override int Next()
    {
        var result = (int)NextLong(0, int.MaxValue);
        return result;
    }

    public override int Next(int maxValue)
    {
        var result = (int)NextLong(0, maxValue);
        return result;
    }

    public override int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        var result = (int)NextLong(minValue, maxValue);
        return result;
    }

    public override void NextBytes(byte[] buffer)
    {
        int remaining = buffer.Length;

        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            var next = BitConverter.GetBytes(NextUlong());
            int n = Math.Min(next.Length, remaining);

            Array.Copy(next, 0, buffer, buffer.Length - remaining, n);
            remaining -= n;
        }
    }

    public override double NextDouble()
    {
        var result = NextUlong() / (ulong.MaxValue + 1.0);
        return result;
    }

    static readonly ulong[] _jump =
    [
        0x84242f96eca9c41d,
        0xa3c65b8776f96855,
        0x5b34a39f070b5837,
        0x4489affce4f31a1e,
        0x2ffeeb0a48316f40,
        0xdc2d9891fe68c022,
        0x3659132bb12fea70,
        0xaac17d8efa43cab8,
        0xc4cb815590989b13,
        0x5ee975283d71c93b,
        0x691548c86c1bd540,
        0x7910c41d10a1e6a5,
        0x0b5fc64563b3e2a8,
        0x047f7684e9fc949d,
        0xb99181f2d8f685ca,
        0x284600e3f30e38c3
    ];

    void init()
    {
        ulong[] t = new ulong[16];

        for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < 64; b++)
            {
                if ((_jump[i] & 1UL << b) != 0)
                    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
                        t[j] ^= _s[(j + _p) & 15];

                NextUlong();
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
            _s[(j + _p) & 15] = t[j];
    }

    readonly ulong[] _s = new ulong[16];
    int _p;
}
```

Note the `public (int P, ulong[] S) State()` method that I added in order to return the state.

Then you could use it to save/restore the state in order to skip iterations like so:

```
XorShift rng1 = new XorShift(Guid.NewGuid());

for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) // Skip 10K random numbers.
{
    rng1.Next();
}

var state = rng1.State(); // RNG state after first 10K iterations.

Console.WriteLine("From first RNG:");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(rng1.Next());

Console.WriteLine("\nFrom second RNG:");
var rng2 = new XorShift(state.P, state.S);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(rng2.Next());
```

The output from this is:

```
From first RNG:
1129543872
1219337207
1574241099
1340742741
892399437
671519662
1202729140
563207978
2085904688
679406100

From second RNG:
1129543872
1219337207
1574241099
1340742741
892399437
671519662
1202729140
563207978
2085904688
679406100
```

Which shows that the results from the second RNG are the same as those from the first one after 10K numbers have been generated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which has the ability to do inverse (going from result back to original) as well as skip in
O(log(N)) to any point in sequence forth and back, see F.Brown paper reference for details. Below is C++ code, I could probably make it C# if you need it and ask

```
class lcg_PLE63
{
    public: typedef uint_fast64_t result_type;
    public: typedef result_type   seed_type;

    public: static constexpr result_type  nbits = 63ULL;
    public: static constexpr result_type  mod   = 1ULL << nbits;
    public: static constexpr result_type  mask  = mod - 1ULL;

    // those values are from P.L'Ecuyer "Efficient and Portable Combined RNGs", Comm.ACM 31(6): 742-749, 774 (1988)
    public: static constexpr result_type  mult  = 2806196910506780709ULL;
    public: static constexpr result_type  add   = 1ULL;

    public: static constexpr seed_type  default_seed   = 1ULL;        

    public: static constexpr float        norm  = float{1.0842021724855044340074528008699e-19};

    private: mutable seed_type _seed;

    public: lcg_PLE63(seed_type seed = default_seed):
        _seed{seed}
    {
    }

    public: lcg_PLE63(lcg_PLE63 const& r):
        _seed{r._seed}
    {
    }

    public: lcg_PLE63(lcg_PLE63&& r):
        _seed{std::move(r._seed)}
    {
    }        

    public: lcg_PLE63& operator=(lcg_PLE63 const& r)
    {
        _seed = r._seed;
        return *this;
    }

    public: lcg_PLE63& operator=(lcg_PLE63&& r)
    {
        _seed = std::move(r._seed);
        return *this;
    }

    public: ~lcg_PLE63()
    {
    }

    public: seed_type seed() const
    {
        return _seed;
    }



int64_t compute_nskip(int64_t ns)
{
    int64_t nskip = ns;
    while (nskip < 0LL)
    {
        uint64_t t = uint64_t(nskip) + mod;
        nskip = int64_t(t);
    }
    return nskip & mask; // keep it inside our bit-range
}

result_type skip(int64_t ns, seed_type seed)
{
    // compute positive number of seeds to skip
    int64_t nskip = compute_nskip(ns);

    // The algorithm here to determine the parameters used to skip ahead is
    // described in the paper F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride,"
    // Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994). This algorithm is able to skip ahead in
    // O(log2(N)) operations instead of O(N). It computes parameters
    // M and C which can then be used to find x_N = M*x_0 + C mod 2^M.

    // initialize constants
    result_type m{ mult }; // original multiplicative constant
    result_type c{ add };  // original additive constant

    result_type m_next{ 1ULL }; // new effective multiplicative constant
    result_type c_next{ 0ULL }; // new effective additive constant

    while (nskip > 0LL)
    {
        if (nskip & 1LL) // check least significant bit for being 1
        {
            m_next = (m_next * m) & mask;
            c_next = (c_next * m + c) & mask;
        }

        c = ((m + 1ULL) * c) & mask;
        m = (m * m) & mask;

        nskip = nskip >> 1LL; // shift right, dropping least significant bit
    }

    // with G and C, we can now find the new seed
    return (m_next * seed + c_next) & mask;
}

    public: static result_type sample(seed_type seed)
    {
        return (mult * seed + add) & mask;
    }

    public: void sample() const
    {
        _seed = sample(_seed);
    }

    public: float number() const
    {
        sample();
        return float(_seed) * norm;
    }

    public: void skip(int64_t ns) const
    {
        _seed = skip(ns, _seed);
    }
};
```